# Can i use only TemporaryFileUploadHandler for a certain FileField?

Tags: django

For a site i just build i have created a custom FileField, AudioFileField. In the AudioFileForm i now want to check wether a file is an audiofile or not. For this i use sox, a commandlinetool i call via subprocess. In the forms to_python function i have copied the code from ImageFileField:

```
#Either we have a path or we
# have to create a temporary one.
if hasattr(data, 'temporary_file_path'):
    file = data.temporary_file_path()
else:
    if hasattr(data, 'read'):
        file = StringIO(data.read())
    else:
        file = StringIO(data['content'])
    # save file to temporary_file_path? Where is temporary_file_path?
    # can i get temporary_file_path from settings, defaults?

check = subprocess.Popen([sox,'--i','-t','%s'%self.path], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
filetype = check.communicate()[0]
if not filetype:
    raise forms.ValidationError('File is not an audiofile')
```

After thinking about this, i thought it could be helpfull to just force the TemporaryFileUploadHandler to be used for AudioFileField. That would save me from the trouble of writing my own code to create a temporary file. How can i do that?

Comment: Thanks for marking it as right :) Would be happy if you vote my answer up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subclass the TemporaryFileUploadhandler Model and rewrite the save method with your custom validation code. And all the associated rituals :)